# How does the TraceProcessing library compare to the TraceEvent lIbrary used by PerfView?

Tags: .net-traceprocessing

There seems to be quite a few different ways to tackle parsing ETW events (TraceProcessing, TraceEvent, ETW2JSON, etc.). I'm interested specifically in the trade offs between the TraceProcessing library and the [TraceEvent](https://github.com/microsoft/perfview/blob/master/documentation/TraceEvent/TraceEventProgrammersGuide.md) library.

- Are they intended for different usecases?
- Did TraceProcessing come about as a follow on to or evolution of TraceEvent?
- Why would one choose the TraceProcessing library instead of TraceEvent library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I am a developer at Microsoft who works on the TraceProcessor project.)

I have a little more familiarity with TraceEvent than with ETW2JSON, but the same answer applies in both cases.

Each was developed by different organizations within Microsoft to best support our own performance and diagnostic investigations. In some cases, we took design inspiration or cues for TraceProcessor from other libraries, but largely we developed it for our specific use cases and according to our own design philosophies.

Those differences mean that each library has its own principles about performance, API design/consistency, and broad-based ETW support vs. well-developed first-class support for certain specific things.

TraceEvent does have .NET/CLR support, but focuses mostly on being a manged wrapper around the C++ ETW APIs.  It does have support for other events, but very limited.

All in all, TraceEvent is great for first-class .NET/CLR data and the "basics" elsewhere.

TraceProcessor gives strong first-class support to the types of system and diagnostic data that you could see in other tools like XPerf and [WPA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/windows-performance-analyzer). We’ve pushed for a clean, consistent, performant API across the library and emphasized strong typing to present each type of data in the most natural shape.

Comment: Are there any events that TraceProcessor wouldn't handle that TraceEvent would?

Comment: TraceProcessor will provide you access to all of the events in the trace, but with different support depending on the type of event. For manifested/tracelogging events, we give an IGenericEvent, which gives nice by-index or by-name access to the fields. For special events like context switches, we'll go further and give you a first-class IContextSwitch. If our support doesn't go far enough, you can access the raw, unparsed events and handle the parsing according to your needs. We don't have any special first-class support for .NET events, though, so you just get an IGenericEvent for those.

Comment: For IClassicEvents (Classic/MOF), is there anyway to access that event's data (i.e. the event type MOF class properties)? Or is it not possible to access that data via TraceProcessor?

Comment: It's not currently possible using the IClassicEvent. Instead, you'd need to get the event as an unparsed event. You could do this using the IFilteredEventConsumer approach listed in this [extensibility page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/trace-processing/extensibility). Dot through to EventContext.Event.Data, and you get access to the bytes in the event payload, which you can either cast to a struct or use the helpers in [EventDataReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windows.eventtracing.eventdatareader?view=trace-processor-dotnet-1.0).

Comment: Note that the approach to extensibility may change in the future.